# libgdx box2D contactlistener

Tags: libgdx, box2d

i am testing collision between two bodies in box2D using contactListener

this is my whole contactListener class i used **world.setContactListener(new Box2DWorld(this))** to add it

```
 public class Box2DWorld implements ContactListener{

World world;
GameScreen gameScreen;
Car car;

public enum BodyName{
    frontWheel,rearWheel,carShell,ground,finishSensor
}

/**
 * this class handles collisions and body userdata
 * @param gameScreen
 */
public Box2DWorld(GameScreen gameScreen) {  
    this.gameScreen = gameScreen;
    world = gameScreen.world;
    this.car = gameScreen.car;
}


/*
 * the debug should be like 
 * 
 * BEGONCONTACT,preSolve,postSolve,......postsolve,ENDCONTACT,BEGINCONTACT,preSolve,postSolve
 * 
 * but i am getting debug like
 * 
 * BEGINCONTACT,preSolve,postSolve,......postsolve,BEGINCONTACT,presolve,ENDCONTACT,preSolve,postSolve...
 * 
 * i can't understand why begincontact appears twice without endcontact in between and also bodies are in contact
 *  even after endcontact
 * 
 */

@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    BodyName bodyA = (BodyName) contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
    BodyName bodyB = (BodyName) contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();


    if((bodyA == BodyName.frontWheel && bodyB == BodyName.ground )||(bodyA == BodyName.ground && bodyB == BodyName.frontWheel)){
        car.frontWheel.onGround = true;
        System.out.println("begin contact");
    }


}   

@Override
public void endContact(Contact contact) {
    BodyName bodyA = (BodyName) contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
    BodyName bodyB = (BodyName) contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();

    if((bodyA == BodyName.frontWheel && bodyB == BodyName.ground )||(bodyA == BodyName.ground && bodyB == BodyName.frontWheel)){
        car.frontWheel.onGround = false;
        System.out.println("contact end");  
    }

}

@Override
public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

    BodyName bodyA = (BodyName) contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
    BodyName bodyB = (BodyName) contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();

    if((bodyA == BodyName.frontWheel && bodyB == BodyName.ground )||(bodyA == BodyName.ground && bodyB == BodyName.frontWheel)){
        System.out.println("PreSolve"); 
    }


}

@Override
public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

    BodyName bodyA = (BodyName) contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
    BodyName bodyB = (BodyName) contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();

    if((bodyA == BodyName.frontWheel && bodyB == BodyName.ground )||(bodyA == BodyName.ground && bodyB == BodyName.frontWheel)){
        System.out.println("postSolve");    
    }

}
```

my dedub goes like this

**beginContact** 
preSolve
postSolve
.
.
.
.
.
.
preSolve
postSolve
**beginContact**
preSolve
**endcontact**
postSolve
presolve
.
.
.
.

i can't understand why begincontact is appearing before endcontact

both ground and frontWheel bodies have only 1 fixture each

i can't figure out this from a week pls help me

Comment: You are not checking the case where bodyA == Y and bodyB == X

Comment: i am checking that i just didn;t add that here

Comment: How about you add it then, so that people don't waste their time and yours by giving you suggestions for things you have already done. I think there must be something else you "didn't add here" because it would be a huge bug in Box2D if a pair of bodies had two BeginContact events before the EndContact happened.

Comment: i am really srry that i didn't add that, i have no experience in asking questions ,please forgive me . i like your blog very much , you have been a great help to me and a lot of people

Comment: @iforce2d i edited my question now , i don't know whether i should be adding more pls say me if i am missing anythig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a contact is between two fixtures, not two bodies.

I would guess that your ground is made from many fixtures, and they are all on the same ground body right? As the wheel rolls over the fixtures it can touch more than one fixture at a time, so you can get begin(fixture1), begin(fixture2), end(fixture1) in that order. It's quite normal. I think if you print out the ground fixture involved in each contact event, you would see what I mean.

If you want to know when the wheel is touching the ground, you need to track the total number of fixtures currently touching. You can do that by incrementing a counter when you get a 'begin' event, and decrement it when you get an 'end' event. Then you can check the counter any time, if it is more than zero the wheel is touching the ground.

Comment: i changed it to single fixture but the problem continues <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/6b35p6whz/Untitled_2.png">

Comment: Depending on what type of shape it is, the actual exported fixtures may not be the same. For example, Box2D can only use convex polygons with maximum of 8 vertices so when you export a large polygon, or one that has concave parts, RUBE will create the individual polygons that Box2D can use. As I mentioned, what you are seeing is not really a problem, it's the expected behavior. Did you try printing out the fixtures that each contact event was caused by?

Comment: wow great that fixed it , like you said those begin contact are from different fixtures. Didn't know that box2D can have only 8 vertices .thanks for the help :)